# Settings API updated messages won't show if custom admin page not hooked into add_options_page()

Tags: plugin-development

Been playing around with the Settings API and found that messages (for success or errors) are only displayed when a settings page is hooked into WordPress menu via add_options_page(). Anything else will not work e.g. add_dashboard_page(). Would like to know if this is true? Sample code I tried with is the answer containing the "RegisteredSettingsTest" class at [Where to hook register_settings for Settings API when also want to update options outside of Settings API?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9774/where-to-hook-register-settings-for-settings-api-when-also-want-to-up)

Answer (score 23):

Thanks Chip (*excellent Settings API tutorial*) and t31os (*great snippet of code for quick testing*) for both your suggestions.

I did some further digging and found that the default messages can indeed be displayed if I hook into any menu but only if the function [settings_errors()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/settings_errors) is called.

For example, modifying t31os code as follows:

```
<div class="wrap">
  <h2>Test</h2>
  <?php settings_errors(); ?>
  <form action="options.php" method="post">
```

Custom error messages can also be added by calling the [add_settings_error()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_settings_error) function for displaying success or failure message by specifying the `$type` parameter as either 'error' or 'updated'.

Comment: this had me stumped for a while too!
using `settings_errors();` did the trick, thanks for posting a follow up Jesse!

Answer (score 10):

I use Settings API integration with my Theme,use `add_theme_page()`, and have no problem displaying admin notices.

I suspect that it is a problem with your *code* rather than a Settings API limitation.

Can you post your actual code, so we can help you resolve any code-related issues?

**EDIT**

You may need to output your admin notices explicitly. For example, here is what I use in my settings page markup function:

```
<?php if ( isset( $_GET['settings-updated'] ) ) {
    echo "<div class='updated'><p>Theme settings updated successfully.</p></div>";
} ?>
```

I assume you could do something similar for error notices, as well.

Comment: See updated answer.

Comment: The code I used can be found at [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/ZbPCec8Q). Apologies if I am not clear enough. What I observe is if I hooked into a menu via `add_options_page()` and save the settings, a "Settings saved" message will be displayed. However, if I changed the code to use `add_theme_page()` or `add_dashboard_page()`, then the default "Settings saved" message will not appear.

Comment: Right... did you add code as per the example above? You have to add it explicitly to your settings page markup function.

Comment: I'm flattered you used my test code to build on top of, Chip is correct that you'll need to add the notice yourself explicitly. Best of luck with your settings page Jesse.. :)